# How to pass the result of a function as a Macro variable?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, pointers, macros

Say I've set up a macro expansion as follows...

```
#define WARN_START @"DANGER"
#define WARN_RESET @"THE COAST IS CLEAR"
#define WARN(x) WARN_START x WARN_RESET
```

<kbd>INPUT</kbd>   `WARN(@"*** Your boss is coming. ***")`

<kbd>OUTPUT</kbd>`DANGER *** Your boss is coming. *** THE COAST IS CLEAR`  ✅

and lets suppose I have a function…

```
NSString * WhosComing(void){ return @"*** Some fool. ***"; }
```

**How can I pass the result of such a function to the macro, without first assigning it to a variable, i.e.**

`WARN(WhosComing())`

<kbd>ERROR</kbd>`expected ')'`

I've messed around with  extra parenthesis, i.e.

`#define WARN((x))`…. or ...`WARN_START (x) WARN_RESET` but…

<kbd>ERROR</kbd>`invalid operands to binary expression`, etc.

as well as trying to pass the cuntion as a pointer, or something, i.e. `WARN(&WhosComing())`, to no avail.  I'm sure this is possible / straightforward… but I don't have a CS degree, so I never learned how..  Easy answer for someone?

Comment: kbd is not for showing input and output that is for showing KeyBoard's keys.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya what, you don't like it?

Comment: No, `Input:` and `Output :` will look better instead of button style.

Comment: Do you not want to assign it to a variable because you want to avoid writing that code repeatedly or is some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't have the result of the function inserted at compile-time, as obviously the function's result doesn't exist until it is executed. But you can do something like this:

```
#define WARN(x) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", WARN_START, (x), WARN_RESET]
```

But that's no better than a function, is it? If the argument to the macro were a literal string, you could write it the way you want. But since the argument's value is not even known at compile time, there's not a whole lot you can do with it at the macro-expansion stage, so emitting an expression that will produce the value you want at run time is pretty much your only option.

Comment: The other answer is good too, but I used this.. and actually simplified? it a bit, as `#define WARN(x) [NSString stringWithFormat:WARN_START %@" WARN_RESET, (x)]`  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you are attempting with a macro. It is a feature of the C language (and hence Objective-C, C++) that adjacent string literals are concatenated during compilation and this is extended for Objective-C to included `NSString` literals.

Your macro expands to:

```
@"DANGER" @"*** Your boss is coming. ***" @"THE COAST IS CLEAR"
```

and the compiler then concatenates these 3 literals into 1.

However pass in your function and you get:

```
@"DANGER" WhosComing() @"THE COAST IS CLEAR"
```

which is invalid code.

There are various solutions; you could use a real function, inlining it if are really concerned over the cost of the function call:

```
NS_INLINE NSString *WARN(NSString *msg)
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", WARN_START, msg, WARN_RESET];
}
```